# Event Listener not triggering after transaction using React & ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, react, smart-contract

I'm trying to retrieve the token IDs of a minting operation in my front-end.

I was trying to use the Transfer event of my ER721A contract

```js
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "from",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "to",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "tokenId",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Transfer",
      "type": "event"
    },
```

Here is my minting function call, the idea is to get the tokenID just afeter the minting is complete to display it a modal.

```js
async function mint() {
      try {
        const contract = web3Context.contract;
        const transaction = await contract.mint(count, {
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther((Number(price) * count).toString()),
        });
        toast.promise(transaction.wait(), {
          pending: "Minting in progress ⛏️",
          success: "NFT Minted ",
          error: "Transaction rejected ",
        });
        await transaction.wait();
        contract.on("Transfer", (tokenId) => {
          console.log(tokenId);
        });
      } catch (e: any) {
        console.log(e);
        toast.error("Transaction rejected ");
      }
  }
```

The minting is going well, but nothing is logged into the console, like if the `contract.on` method was not triggered.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that `contract.on` starts when the transaction is already mined. You can try writing `contract.on` before making the `transaction`, and a `contract.off` after you get your event.

However, there's a better way that doesn't include making a listener. You can pick up the event from the receipt of the transaction:

```js
const receipt = await transaction.wait();
console.log(receipt.logs)
```

This should show all events from the transaction, then you can filter for your `Transfer` -> `tokenId`, like this:

```js
const transferEventId = ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")

for (let i=0; i<receipt.logs.length; i++) {
    if (receipt.logs[i].address.toLowerCase() == contract.address.toLowerCase()) {
        if (receipt.logs[i].topics[0] == transferEventId) {
            const tokenId = BigNumber.from(receipt.logs[i].topics[3]).toString()
            console.log(tokenId)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I do get the events as an array of objects, each containing hashes & block number. 
How should I filter that afterwards ?

Comment: @Matos2802 I've edited the answer to show how :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Did you see my reply bellow too ? It's working the way I wanted, with way less code. What do you think ?

Comment: @Matos2802 If it works it works. You're giving some load to your RPC node provider though. Also maybe using contract.once is better than contract.on in your case (https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-once) so you're freeing some resources at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Code was almost good, just positionning the event listener before the `await transaction.wait();` and giving to the callback params all the event params (not only tokenId) worked as excepted.

```js
  contract.on("Transfer", (form, to, tokenId) => {
          console.log(tokenId);
        });
        await transaction.wait();
```

Result, for tokenId #15 is `BigNumber {_hex: '0x0f', _isBigNumber: true}`